# JS Class: Difference between ES6 myFunc(){..} and ES5 myFunc = function() {...} in a class declaration

Tags: javascript, es6-class, function-expression, class-fields

In the following code,

```
class PersonClass {
  constructor(fname) {
    this.fname = fname;
  }
  read = function() { console.log('I am reading') }
  speak () { console.log('I am speaking'); }
}

//Instantiate 
let p1 = new PersonClass('Raj')
```

`read = function() { console.log('I am reading') }` becomes a property of newly created instance i.e.

`p1.hasOwnProperty('read')` is `true`

as opposed to `speak() { console.log('I am speaking'); }` gets assigned to `PersonClass.prototype`. i.e.

`p1.hasOwnProperty('speak')` is `False`

`p1.__proto__.hasOwnProperty('speak')` is `true`

Can somebody pls explain why this happens.

Essentially what's the diff between two way of method declarations inside class.

I thought `speak() {...}` was just shorter syntax for `speak = function() {...}` (in ES6)

Thanks

Comment: because js follows prototypal inheritance.

Comment: No, method syntax is not an abbreviation of class properties.

Comment: The `variableName = ...` syntax in the class' body is equivalent to the `this.variableName = ...` statement in the `constructor`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The

```
read = function() { console.log('I am reading') }
```

is new *class field* syntax. It's effectively the same as assigning to the `read` property of the instance inside the constructor:

```
class PersonClass {
  constructor(fname) {
    this.read = function() {
      console.log('I am reading')
    }
    this.fname = fname;
  }
  speak() {
    console.log('I am speaking');
  }
}
```

`speak`, on the other hand, is an ordinary class method, which means it's on the prototype, `PersonClass.prototype`, which is the same thing as `Object.getPrototypeOf(p1)`, which is the same thing as `p1.__proto__` (deprecated syntax).

```js
class PersonClass {
  constructor(fname) {
    this.read = function() {
      console.log('I am reading')
    }
    this.fname = fname;
  }
  speak() {
    console.log('I am speaking');
  }
}
let p1 = new PersonClass('Raj')
console.log(
  PersonClass.prototype.hasOwnProperty('speak'),
  Object.getPrototypeOf(p1) === PersonClass.prototype,
  p1.__proto__ === PersonClass.prototype
);
```

So, the `speak` property is on the *internal prototype* of the instance, not on the instance itself. The `read` property is a direct property of the instance, just like the `fname` property.

Keep in mind that class field syntax is [still an experimental proposal](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-class-fields) (stage 3). It's implemented in Chrome, at least, but it's not completely official yet.

Comment: You might want to mention that class properties are still a proposal only